# How to attach existing document in sharepoint to a newly created contact

Tags: contacts

I have an existing document folder that includes summaries of various clients.  I have now added a contact's list and would like to attach the existing documents to the newly created contact as an attachment. I know how to attach a document form a folder on my computer or network. I can not figure out how to attach or link the document that is already saved to my document folder on sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to create a hyperlink column... then link it with the folder having the documents.

But if you want to add it as attachments, you will need to either manually do it by downloading and then attaching.

Or you can write a custom code to achieve this